# Error: Missing version in readMessageBegin, old client?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, sandbox

When i was working with my HBase java client , i got an error showing

```
org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Missing version in readMessageBegin, old client?
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:213)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.Hbase$Client.recv_getTableNames(Hbase.java:867)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.Hbase$Client.getTableNames(Hbase.java:855)
at org.HBaseJDBC.HBaseClient.main(HBaseClient.java:61)
```

And my Java code follows,

```
 TTransport socket = new TSocket("192.168.1.80", 60000);// IP Host Name
        TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(socket, true, true);// Note here
        Hbase.Client client = new Hbase.Client(protocol);
        socket.open();
        try {
            for (ByteBuffer name : client.getTableNames()) { 
                //code
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Here my HBase running on hortonworks sandbox virtual machine , and my java client is running in local host. Why am getting this error? Am using HBase-server 0.98.4 version.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm having the same problem...